# Explain the differentiability and the analyticity

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Explain the differentiability and the analyticity of the complex-valued function 
$$f(z)=|z|^2$$

at $z = 0$.

I know $z=a+bi,\space f(a,b)=a^2+b^2$ what should I do next?

Comment: Next you should apply the definition of "analytic" and "differentiable" to the function $f$. If you don't know what those definitions are, then instead you should next find them in your book or notes, and read them, _then_ try to apply them.

Comment: $$f(z) = |z|^2 = \sqrt{\Im(z)^2 + \Re(z)^2} ^2 = \Im(z)^2 + \Re(z)^2$$
That might help

Answer (score -1):

f(z)=$(x^2+y^2)+i.0$

so,u(x,y)=$x^2+y^2$,v(x,y)=0

then $u_x=2x,u_y=2y,v_x=0,v_y=0$

C-R equations are satisfied only at origin and nowhere else

therefore ,f(z) is not differentiable at any point except origin but **might be differentiable at origin**.(as f(z) is not differentiable at points where C-R equation is not satisfied but it may or may not be differentiable at the points where C-R equations is satisfied)

now,at origin,it is easier to check that f(z) is differentiable

so,f(z)is differentiable at origin but not analytic there(for analyticity at a point,f(z) must be differentiable at the point as well as it's neighbourhood)